# Pyglet : using on_resize() event causes my text to disapear

Tags: python, text, pyglet

My text doesn't show up when I use on_resize() event.
To be more specific, the problem come from the "return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED" statement.

Here's a short example :

```
import pyglet;from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world', font_size=36)

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED

@window.event
def on_draw():label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

This code results in a black screen.
I have to remove the return statement in the on_resize event to make it work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I still don't understand why the above code doesn't work, But I finally found a solution :

```
import pyglet;from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world', font_size=36)

# adding gluPerspective, don't know why and dont want to use it, but no choice...
gluPerspective(60., window.width / float(window.height), .1, 1000.)

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED

@window.event
def on_draw():
    # adding a translation because of gluPerspective()
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(0, -200, -450)
    label.draw()
    glPopMatrix()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Last precision : gluPerspective mustn't to be in the on_resize() event, because in that case, the text disappear as soon as the user resizes the window...